# isset in Session Won't Work

Tags: php, html, session

i created a login system which determines the user if he/she is logged in using a `$_SESSION['logged_in]=true;` session code. But somehow when a user closes his/her browser and come back to page, it will give them an error about a session malfunction thing. So I used `if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']==true)){` but when I open my site it gives me an error saying

> Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)

How can I fix this?

Comment: `isset($_SESSION['logged_in']==true)` --- what does this mean?

Comment: `if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in'] == true))` or `if (!empty($_SESSION['logged_in']))` for short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a typo. Instead of

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']==true)){
```

use

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])==true){
```

You need to check whether the session is set initially, not the value of the session.

[EDIT]:
As you are assigning the value of the session to `true`, it is better to add more checking of the value of the session, so it becomes:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])==true && $_SESSION['logged_in'] == true){
```

Comment: So If I want to set a session to logged_in = true; will I use 'isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])=true;' or just '$_SESSION['logged_in']=true; ?

Comment: If you want to assign the value to `$_SESSION['logged_in']`, then use `$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;`. The function `isset` is just to check whether you have set the session before.

Comment: That changes the entire check. Even if logged_in is set tofalse it would report true. Because it is set.

Comment: It depends on how people code, e.g. they may have either unset for not logged in or set to `true` if logged in. Anyway I've edited my answer to accommodate such possibilities. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Change like this,

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in']==true ){ 
 //do your stuff.
}
```